# Could an ISP access a site viewed through an iframe on a HTTPS site?

Tags: iframe, https

Let's say you have a website at https://foo.com and on this site you have an iframe that is pointing at another site https://bar.com

So obviously an ISP could see that you accessed foo.com, would they know you accessed bar.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - it is still your browser which makes the dns lookup/request to the second site.

Comment: The ISP cannot "access" the iframe, but can see the domain (with DNS and/or SNI), and the approximate size of each resources exchanged with your browser.

Comment: Does this also mean the ISP cannot inject code such as scripts into the HTML file itself?

Comment: The ISP could hijack your DNS requests and send you elsewhere. It would have to be a very specific attack though.